# How to render pages as we go in PHP?

Tags: php

It's really weird, I just changed server last week and I have a large script that process lots of information (personal script).

What it does it add stuff to the database with a foreach and then echo where it is (ex: "ID #27 was processed") and so on until its done. With the old server, I would see this "echo" script run one by one but with my new server, it shows a blank page with the hourglass until it's loaded/done.

Is there a config on the server or PHP that can show me the page as it is constructed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the `php.ini`, you can set `output_buffering = Off` to disable this behavior entirely.  Otherwise, use `flush()`  as suggested by others.

I believe the default setting for `output_buffering` is `4096`. If the new server is set much higher, you might also try simply lowering it rather than turning it off to achieve similar behavior to your old server without losing buffering entirely.

**EDIT** [According to PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php), Apache `mod_gzip` may do its own output buffering which prevents `flush()` from working.

Comment: But this would possibly affect many pages where buffering is indeed useful.

Comment: if my php.ini settings is already set to output_buffering = Off, is it normal that it still only echo everything if page is totally loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Calling [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after each relevant output might help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) and/or [ob_flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) after the echos, you output stream may be buffered.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you push the output to the client using [flush()](http://nl2.php.net/flush).
There are quite a few notes on flush on the php page, see the description.

For example: `flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser.`.

This could instantly explain the entire situation.
Can you validate these notes aren't the cause?